# Matlab: How to get the surface (m2) of an area from which i have 1 coordinate

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, 2d, geometry-surface

I have a binary image in matlab and i have a centroid of an area  (see the * in the picture) which was previously calculated. Now based on this centroid x and y, i would like to get to get the surface (m2) of the circle the centroid is in. But i don't know how to select an area which is very similar to the rest of the circles and i only know the centroid of the one i want. Any suggestions ? Thx in advance .

[image]

Comment: are you looking for help with MATLAB specifically or are you interested in learning the general morphological concepts behind this? If it's the latter, I'd recommend [dsp.se] (despite the name, Image processing questions are also welcome). Please do not cross-post it there, we'll take care of it if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: Thx !
Well i'm interested in both. I'll keep that site in mind for any future questions regarding the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy with *morphological reconstruction*. While I don't know how you can access the matlab implementation, you should use a black image as a single white pixel at your centroid position as the marker image, and your shown binary image as the mask image, and the resolut of a morphological reconstruction by dilation will be an image just showing the selected circle in white. Count white pixels and you are done.

Comment: Im matlab it is :

`marker = false(size(mask));`

`marker(floor(centroids(:,2)),floor(centroids(:,1)) ) = true;`

`im = imreconstruct(marker,mask);`

 `cc = bwconncomp(im);`

        `stats = regionprops(cc, 'area');`

        `area = cat(1, stats.Area)`